# Movie with intro where man kills two girls in a field

Tags: identify-this-movie, crime

This has been driving me crazy for 10 years, maybe more. I saw it on TV and only watched the intro and got kinda scared (yeah I was very young) so I didn't watch past the intro, thus I can't describe more than this. But I'd like to watch it again.

What I remember:
English-spoken American movie from the 90s or early 00's (I think). 
The intro starts with this scene where a man kills two girls who were playing in the field. The filter on this scene was kinda yellowtoned. The man was big/broad, I think dark and they didn't show his face. He assaulted one girl and the other girl ran off but he caught up and hit her with a bat or a branch. The girls might have been twins. 
Before or after this scene you see a (another) man sitting on the bus. I think this part of the movie takes part in modern time (so I guess that would be the 90's). The previous part looked a bit older cause of the yellowish filter and it took place in the countryside, though I'm not sure.

That's all I recall. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems Danielle has your movie

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was searching for the same movie! I remember when he kills the 2nd girl, you see the blood splattering on the flowers in the field... I have searched and searched and I think it is this movie:

*[Carolina Skeletons](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101549/reviews?ref_=tt_urv)* based on David Stout's [novel of the same name](http://articles.latimes.com/1988-07-24/books/bk-10393_1_david-stout).

Judging from the user review about the terrifying open scene, I think it's the same movie.

The movie is currently available on Youtube:

Comment: Wow- I just found the whole movie on YouTube- this is definitely it! Opening scene still scares the crap out of, even though I'm not a kid anymore! Here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRaz3nCMa9k

Comment: never thought I would find it again, this has been on my mind for so many years. Thanks for posting the link!

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like Stephen King's serial thriller made to movie, [The Green Mile](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120689/?ref_=nv_sr_1) with Tom Hanks and the late Michael Clarke Duncan. In it, the two girls are killed by a "man". Joe Coffey finds the girls and tries to heal them, but is too late. The cops (or someone) finds Coffey with the girls and assumes the "Big Black Man" killed the poor little white girls. The story revolves around the turn of events leading up to Coffey getting fried in the electric chair.

Comment: @ Paulster2 thx for your reply but I don't think it's the Green Mile. I know there are similarities, murder of 2 young girls on the countryside sounds like it. But in the Green Mile they only show this farmer-ish skinny type of guy threatening the girls in a dark room and this scene happened near the end of GM. The movie I saw was the intro of the movie and you could specifically see a big man chasing the girls in the field and hurting them. I don't remember that the Green Mile actually shows the girls being hurt. And the scene before/after it should have some guy sitting in the bus.

Comment: @kim ... fair enough.